# Couchbase startkey_docid not working as we expect it

Tags: java, couchbase

So it appears that the startkey_docid is not working as we would expect it to with couchbase.

We do have a startkey defined, and that works well with the dates,but when combined with a startkey_docid we are not seeing the expected result. Is this not possible with a complexKey?

We are calling directly to Couchbase via REST interface, we are using the Java client, but are calling directly here to remove possibility of a bug in the client.

Notice complex Key with date array:

```
startkey=[[2013,11,11,23,12,0],"EVERYONE"]&startkey_docid=41070cfc-a85c-424c-9b87-fce0616c77c1&skip=1&descending=true
```

View:

```
function (doc, meta) 
{
  if(meta.type == "json" && doc.type == "POST" && doc.created != null) 
  {
    emit([dateToArray(doc.created), doc.visibility], null);
  }
}
```

Notice in the result to only skipped of 4 rows is the first. The startkey_docid is actually the middle result, so what we expected is to only have the last doc. Why? because our understanding is the call should have started with that doc and skipped it to only show the last row. Is there a bug or something we are missing?

```
{
    total_rows: 4,
    rows: [{
        id: "6e57a775-1e96-4ac3-95c1-f2218355aa3d",
        key: [ [2013, 11, 11, 20, 29, 19], "EVERYONE"],
        value: null
    }, {
        id: "41070cfc-a85c-424c-9b87-fce0616c77c1",
        key: [ [2013, 11, 11, 20, 28, 21], "EVERYONE"],
        value: null
    }, {
        id: "a4a6cf44-8a82-494a-a2b9-f6a3ec629f17",
        key: [ [2013, 11, 8, 1, 17, 46], "EVERYONE"],
        value: null
    }]
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to use it without `descending=true`? It's just a guess, but maybe it cause some unexpected behavior.

Comment: Also read this post http://blog.couchbase.com/pagination-couchbase

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Has been tried without descending. Also we have already read that blog post and the docs. So we figure we are going about it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't properly documented, which led me to have similar problems as you. To get it to behave correctly, you need to pass in both the `docid` of the last document, and **set the key of the last document as `startkey`**. If you don't change `startkey` each time you paginate, you'll get the same page over and over.